# Printing item from a sublist

Tags: python, list, sublist

```
data = [['a','b'], ['a','c']]
print data[0[0]]
>>> 0
```

When I try this, I get an error. How could I print the 1st item from 1st list?

Comment: Wow, 7 answers in 25 seconds.

Comment: @Chris - and they're all the same :O

Comment: @Chris -- And they're all identical.  Must be only 1 good way to solve this problem, and it must be a pretty simple problem :).

Comment: FYI the error is `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`, which tells you that you are subscripting (`[]`) an `int`. So you can work out that it's `0[0]` that doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

You should try this:

```
print data[0][0]
```

This works because `data[0]` is the list `['a', 'b']`, so `data[0][0]` is `['a', 'b'][0]` which is just `'a'`.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to switch the location of your brackets:

```
print data[0][0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You have accessed it in the wrong way, try this instead

```
print data[0][0]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to write

```
print data[0][0]
```

`data[0]` selects the first list, then the additional `[0]` on the end selects the first element from the first list.

Answer (score 2):

use `data[0][0]`:

```
>>> data = [['a','b'], ['a','c']]
>>> print data[0][0]
a
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the first list by data[0], then get the first element of that list with [0], like this:

```
data[0][0]
```